# What determines the upper limit of the capacitive load on a DAC?

Tags: amplifier, capacitance, dac

I need to drive a number of piezoelectric actuators. The [AD5535B](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5535B.pdf) seems promising because of the high number of channels and low cost (and I happen to be able to borrow one for testing) but sadly, the capacitance of my actuators is (way) more than the 200pF specified as maximum in the datasheet.

I can think of two reasons that this limit is specified,

1. The output source current is limited. A larger capacitance would exceed this rating for large voltage steps.
2. The amplifier circuit could become unstable due to the capacitive load.

I would think that both problems would be solved by simply placing a >[400K](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200V%2F500uA+to+kOhm) resistor in series with the load; maybe a 1M resistor as specified as minimum resistive load in the datasheet. Would that be enough to be able to drive arbitrary capacitive loads?

Comment: Yes, since you're no longer driving a capacitive load with the output of the DAC, you're largely driving the resistor.  If you're OK with the reduction in bandwidth from the RC, you should be fine.

Comment: @JohnD cool! Thanks

Comment: From the charts in the datasheet, it looks like stability is not an issue even with large values of capacitance. So the main issue would be whether the slew rate matches your needs.